# Pattern textbox HTML for currency

Tags: html, angularjs, design-patterns, typescript, currency

I have a textbox inside a project with HTML, Angular 2 and Typescript.
How to accept only numbers and one dot OR one comma.
It has to accept *infinite numbers + dot OR comma + two numbers*.

2.34 accept
1326262566.43 accept
4,08 accept
0,12 accept
45736573,98 accept

I can save it inside a String variable, doesn't need to be a number type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a regExp for you - [go here](https://regex101.com/r/nh8swN/2)

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex :

```
\d{1,}[\,\.]{1}\d{1,2}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery Validation Plugin in that case.
Here, you need to define set of rules for each checkboxes, textboxes or any other input elements you are using.
I am not sure whether typescript has some internal validation methods or rules since if it has then you will not require it to do in JQuery way if it doesn't then you can go with JQuery way.
You can also use regex for this.
Please vote and mark the solution if useful.

**Thanks!**